# DataTable cell with multiple lines

Tags: c#, excel, datatable

In Microsoft Excel I can break any cell into multiple lines pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

For example, a single cell with:

```
Line 1 
Line 2
Line 3
```

Is here any way to implement it in DataTable?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by adding a break literal:

```
Value1 + "<br />" + Value2
```

Or in your example:

```
Line 1<br />Line 2<br />Line 3
```